# How to solve homogenous ODE with zero as initial time $t_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to solve the ODE

$$y' = \frac{t + 2y}{2t + y}$$

as general homogenous equation. Thus I'm using general initial conditions $y(t_0) = y_0$ with the only restriction $2t_0 + y_0 \neq 0$ (otherwise the denominator would be zero in the defining equation). Notice, that this condition doesn't imply $t_0 \neq 0$.

At this point I want to solve ODE using a transformation into a homogenous equation. Thus look at it like this

$$y' = \frac{1 + 2\frac{y}{t}}{2 + \frac{y}{t}}$$

Expanding with $t$ in the nominator and denominator shows that the equations are equivalent. Then substituting $z = \frac{y}{t}$ yields the separable equation

$$z' = \frac{1}{t} (\frac{1 + 2z}{2 + z} - z)$$

Now I'm wondering about what happens if the initial value $t_0$ was zero. In this case the substitution doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: What if you let $y = tv$, then $y' = v + t v'$? Substitute and that likely helps.

Answer (score 1):

$$y' = \frac{t + 2y}{2t + y}$$
There are many ways to integrate this Differential Equation, @Moo's trick is one of them. Here is another way:
$$\frac {dy}{(t + 2y)}=\frac  {dt}{(2t + y)}$$
$$\frac {d(t+y)}{3(t + y)}=\frac  {d(t-y)}{(t - y)}$$

Integrate:
$$\ln \left | \dfrac {t+y}{(t-y)^3}  \right|=k \implies \left | \dfrac {t+y}{(t-y)^3}  \right|=c$$